# Can an Intel UHD Graphics 630 support a fourth monitor through USB-A to HDMI?

Tags: usb, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

A co-worker's office computer is an HP ProDesk 400 G7 running on an Intel Core i5 with the graphics card above. Currently, it is hooked up to 3 monitors through HDMI, DP, and VGA. I was wondering if a fourth monitor could be connected through a USB-A to HDMI cable. I couldn't find any information relating to a fourth monitor online, and it looked like the graphics card only supports 3 monitors, wanted to be sure before going through with a purchase.

Any information you can provide would be extremely helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: USB A to HDMI "cables" are not what you'd expect. They emulate a graphics card with software and the chipset in the cable/adapter is designed to talk to that software to push a signal out of the video port. This will put a large CPU load on the PC to add an extra monitor but it is likely to circumvent the limitation of 3 monitors on the integrated graphics. These adapters are also rather low quality for framerate or resolution because they cannot support the bandwidth needed for 1080p at 60 hz.

Answer (score 0):

See the Intel article
[Intel UHD Graphics 630](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/graphics/126790/intel-uhd-graphics-630.html)
for information about all the versions of it that come with each and every
Intel CPU.

However, for all the versions, the Processor Graphics specs give
the same
number:

```
# of Displays Supported        3
```

The article
[Intel HD Graphics with three displays](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Intel_HD_Graphics_with_three_displays)
lists the possible monitor combinations :

| **Display 1** | **Display 2** | **Display 3** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DisplayPort | DisplayPort | HDMI DVI VGA DisplayPort Built-in display |
| DisplayPort HDMI DVI VGA | DisplayPort HDMI DVI VGA | Built-in display |
| DisplayPort HDMI DVI VGA Built-in display | DisplayPort HDMI DVI VGA | Intel® Wireless Disp |

You may only enable the fourth monitor if you disable the internal one
(not recommended).

Also note that particular vendor implementations of some computer
models may further reduce the number of supported monitors.